# Qual é o máximo de casas decimais permitidas no float em PHP?

Tags: php, float

Eu estava usando o Psysh para fazer testes com números do tipo `float`.

Notei que, depois de uma determinada quantidade, ele começa a limitar as casas decimais.

Exemplo:

```
 $float = 1.1234567891011121314

 echo $float; //  1.1234567891011
```

Por que é isso acontece? Existe um máximo suportado? Se sim, qual é o máximo suportado?

Se eu precisar do número completo, como faço para obtê-lo?

Answer (score 6):

> Números de ponto flutuante tem precisão limitada. Embora dependa do sistema, o PHP geralmente utiliza o formato de precisão dupla do IEEE 754, que trará uma precisão máxima devida a arredondamentos da ordem de 1.11e-16. Operações matemáticas incomuns poderão ocasionar erros maiores, e, claro, a propagação de erros deve ser considerada quando várias operações forem realizadas.

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.float.php

> O padrão IEEE 754 (definido pelo Instituto de Engenheiros Eletricistas
>   e Eletrônicos) foi adotado em 1985 e desde então passou por algumas
>   modificações, e define algumas regras de normalização a serem seguidas
>   nas operações e representações de números binários com ponto
>   flutuante. Antes disso, cada fabricante de computadores e outros
>   dispositivos, possuía um formato de representação diferente.

Quanto à precisão da representação numérica, as principais são:

**Simples**

32 bits ou precisão simples (float), equivalente a até 7 dígitos decimais.

1 bit para o sinal.

8 bits para o expoente.

23 bits para a representação da mantissa.

**Dupla**

64 bits ou precisão dupla (double), equivalente a até 15 dígitos decimais.

1 bit destinado para o sinal;

11 bits destinados para o expoente;

52 bits destinados para a mantissa.

Fonte: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: E o que eu preciso fazer para retornar o número completo nesse caso?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar [round](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.round.php)?

Comment: Não foi o que quis dizer, mas pode deixar. Resolvo isso com `number_format`. Valeu